# Starfleet Command plugins

Tags: modeling, scripting

I was just wondering if someone would be so kind as to possibly compile import and export plugins for the old Starfleet Command games?  The games used .mod format for the models. Someone gave me the source code years ago.  Also, the old Milkshape 3D program, someone had created plugins for it under GNU licensing.

I don't have the skill myself to attempt to compile plugins.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! This Q&A platform is about using Blender. All questions concerning the compilation of program code are unfortunately off-topic here. Please be so kind and check out one of the many Blender forums. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Try _Noesis_ - you can import/view the .mod files, and export as .obj (you can even include .mtl files with the .obj, I think). From there, blender can import the .obj files. Site is here - https://richwhitehouse.com/index.php?content=inc_projects.php&showproject=91